# Adding Javascript to a WordPress page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

It seems my code is not running when I add it to my WordPress site. It’s running just fine in VSCode. Other functions are working in the WordPress site, i.e. `alert` functions are responding. My styles are responding as well so I know the problem is not with enqueueing scripts in functions.php.

Perhaps my JS code is not being called in time to link with the HTML files its supposed to? I don’t know.

This is a snippet of what part of my JS code looks like. How can I change this? Or what am I supposed to wrap it in to make it work?

```js
///nav bar size response
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.navbar-nav').toggle();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sub-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
  })
 
  $(".other-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".other-menu").slideToggle();
  })
})

//button toggle
var menu = document.querySelector(".menu")
var menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn")
var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close-btn")

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.add("active");
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.remove("active");
});

//header scroll
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var header = this.document.querySelector("header");
  header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
});
```

Comment: there's a proper way to inject javascript files to a wordpress page, you can do it in your `functions.php` and import it in there. there are a lot of resources you can get via google

Comment: Oh no, i did that fine. I enqueued my scripts and styles and as that side of things is fine. I believe the problem here is my code, or maybe it’s format. While it works when i run it live on vscode, it doesn’t seem to be aligning once i try and run it on wordpress. Like i said, i cleared my js and wrote a single   ‘’’ alert(‘i am here’)  ‘’’ function. That worked and i got the alert when i refreshed, so my enqueueing is fine

Comment: try to check your your console for errors, since after the subsequent errors, the scripts below it won't run. like your navbar toggle, move it inside the document ready, without checking for js errors, we're just guessing on our side

Comment: i got it. my html and js events were not firing in sync. I wrapped it in an event listener for DOMContentLoad. it's working now